# Save elasticsearch.Config struct to a JSON file

Tags: json, go, elasticsearch

I would like to save an elasticsearch.Config struct to a JSON file. The code looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/elastic/go-elasticsearch"
    "io/ioutil"
)

var EsConfig elasticsearch.Config

func main() {
    EsConfig.Addresses = append(EsConfig.Addresses, "http://localhost:9200")
    EsConfig.Username = "testuser"
    EsConfig.Password = "testpwd"
    js, err := json.MarshalIndent(EsConfig, "", " ") //js is nil
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("After marshalling: %v\n", err)
    }
    err = ioutil.WriteFile("testconfig.json", js, 0644) //output fine is empty
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("After WriteFile %v\n", err)
    }
}
```

however the js variable is always nil and getting error
After marshalling: json: unsupported type: func(int) time.Duration
Please, what am I missing here?

Comment: You're discarding the error returned from `MarshalIndent`. Any time a function isn't doing what you expect, and it has an error return value, *check the error*.

Comment: Adrian, thanks for your response, this is how it looks like if I use some code I found on Internet without thinking. I'm checking the error and getting After marshalling: json: unsupported type: func(int) time.Duration (I changed the code in my original post accordingly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elasticsearch.Config` contains exported `RetryBackoff` field of said type `func(int) time.Duration`. By default, `json.Marshall` tries to marshal all exported fields and, for obvious reason, fails to do so.
AFAIK, the only way to customize struct fields marshaling is struct tags, and you can not add them to another package type. So the only way I see is to make your own struct with necessary fields from `elasticsearch.Config`, fill and then marshal it.